# How to merge two columns of a pivot_table from pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I obtained a dataframe using pd.pivot_table, that looks like this:

```
    foo      bar      
Cond1     60   65    60    65
Cond2                      
50        200  210  16.7  15.2
100       200  210  14.9  13.5
```

I need to get an output that looks like this by merging the foo and bar columns:

```
           foo(bar)      
    Cond1     60          65
    Cond2                      
    50        200(16.7)  210(15.2)
    100       200(14.9)  210(13.5)
```

Is this possible in python using only pandas or numpy or internal libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for no `MultiIndex` in ouput with [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), casting to strings and last join by `+`:

```
df1 = df.xs('foo', axis=1, level=0).astype(str)
df2 = df.xs('bar', axis=1, level=0).astype(str)

df = df1 + '(' + df2 + ')'
```

Solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.xs('foo', axis=1, level=0, drop_level=False).astype(str)
df2 = df.xs('bar', axis=1, level=0, drop_level=False).astype(str)

df = df1.rename(columns={'foo':'foo(bar)'})+'('+ df2.rename(columns={'bar':'foo(bar)'})+ ')'
```